# What authentication methods are supported by imapsync to work with Google Apps accounts?

Tags: imapsync

Will any of these authentication options be persistent despite a password change on the Google Account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked of Google Apps Support

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it only does password-based authentication.

However, if you [set up](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) that password will not change with your regular password (and will not require second-factor tokens if you have 2fa enabled).

Comment: imapsync supports xoauth (obsolete) and also xoauth2 authentication mechanism via openssl. See  http://imapsync.lamiral.info/FAQ.d/FAQ.Gmail.txt which gives http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync_list/msg02129.html and https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync/pull/25/files
and https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync/pull/25/files